# C language, convert and combine 2 strings into a double

Tags: c

I require assistance with my C programming and since my professor is too busy to respond (6th day now can't be found in his office, nor replying to emails).
Suppose I have a structure defined as

```
typedef struct {
    char whole[1000];
    char decimal[1000];
    double number;
} record;
```

where `whole` represents the whole part of the number `(ex. 10, 20, 301, 123, 1005...)` and the `decimal` represents the decimal part of the number `(10.123, 20.22123, 301.99181, 123.558123...)`. the numbers are treated as strings and written in a binary file, ex.

```
10 1234 (10 is the whole part and 1234 is the decimal part of the number = 10.1234)
20 211291 (20.211291)
301 2102190 (301.2102190)
1 56615 (1.56615)
988 001 (988.001)
etc.
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char whole[1000];
    char decimal[1000];
    double number;
} record;

int cmp(record *a, record *b) {
    ????
    return ???;
}
main()
{
    FILE *f = fopen("records.bin", "r+b");
    if (!f)
        exit(1);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(f);
    long N = size / sizeof(record);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    record *z = malloc(size);
    fread(z, sizeof(record), N, f);
    qsort(z, N, sizeof(record), (int(*)(const void*, const void*))cmp);
    /* fopen (wb) fwrite(...) flush, free, fclose*/
    ...
}
```

How would I write the compare function to take those 2 strings (whole and decimal) and combine them into one double which I would then sort ascending?
I've tried using `atof` and `sscanf` but not so sure on how to exactly do it with a binary file structure in the compare function.

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with the "binary file structure". `cmp` doesn't need to know how the `record` was constructed or where it came from.  So your statement "not so sure on how to exactly do it with a binary file structure" is an irrelevant point. So please show your attempted `atof` and `sscanf` code as they should not depend on the file format at all.

Comment: Don't cast function pointers.

Comment: Why does your `record` structure contain 1 "whole" string, 1 "decimal" string, but 1000 numbers?

Comment: @melpomene because I didn't want to write maxn where maxn is an arbitrarily large number. You have a lot of whole parts and a lot of decimal parts that form a lot of double numbers, so I put 1000 instead.

Comment: That binary file looks like a text file to me. Hex dump a few characters.

Comment: @kaylum well, I tried using sscanf(a.whole, "%lf %lf", &a1, &a2); and sscanf(b.decimal, "%lf %lf", &b1, &b2);

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean Yes, it is a text in binary.

Comment: Do you really need to handle numbers with 1000 digits? If you try to convert such a large number to `double`, it won't work. On most systems, the largest double has around 300 digits.

Comment: And why do you have an array in the `number` field? If the record just represents a single number, with 1000 digits before the decimal, and 1000 digits after the decimal, it only needs a single `number` field.

Comment: make it go first by create the `record` objects directly in the code, get those functions working - like cmp. Then get the read from a file working

Comment: "Yes, it is a text in binary. " that doesn't mean anything. When you look at the file with vi or notepad does it look like a bunch of digits or does it look like junk?

Comment: It looks like junk, it's formatted. And thanks for pointing an error, there is no field in     -number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using this `struct`:

```
typedef struct {
    char whole[1000];
    char decimal[1000];
    double number[1000]; 
} record;
```

You would be much better off using this:

```
typedef struct {
    char whole[1000];
    char decimal[1000];
    double number;
} record;
```

Then creating an array of `record` structs, something like this:

```
size_t starting_size = 10;
record *records = malloc(starting_size * sizeof(record));
```

Which allocates an initial `10` records. If there happens to be more lines in the file, you can [`realloc()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm) more space if needed.

> `realloc()` resizes the memory block pointed to, which was previously allocated by `malloc()`.

### How to read your file successfully:

You can simply read the file using [`fscanf()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm), as pointed out in the other answer. Once these values are read into strings, you can simply concatenate everything into one string, then convert the string to a `double` using [`atof()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atof.htm).

Here is an example:

```
char *whole = 123;
char *decimal = 456;
char *point = ".";
double number;

char *whole_number = malloc(strlen(whole) + strlen(decimal) + 2); 
/* check return value */

*whole_number = '\0';
strcat(whole_number, whole);
strcat(whole_number, point);
strcat(whole_number, decimal);

/* string "123.456" created */

number = atof(whole_number);

/* double number = 123.456 created */
/* free() whole_number later */
```

Once this is done, you can then [`qsort`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm) your array of structs in ascending order. This does need a more complete `cmp` function. You function can possibly be this:

```
int cmp_func(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const record *num1 = (const record *)a;
    const record *num2 = (const record *)b;

    if (num1->number > num2->number) {
        return +1;
    } else if (num1->number < num2->number) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then you can simply sort your array with a call like this:

```
qsort(records, N, sizeof(record), cmp_func);
```

### Here is some example code that that demonstrates this:

**Note:** This code is just here to give an example of how to write this program. Simply following the above steps will simply allow you to fix your approach.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUMSIZE 1000
#define INITIALSIZE 10

typedef struct {
    char whole[NUMSIZE+1];
    char decimal[NUMSIZE+1];
    double number;
} record_t;

typedef struct {
    record_t *rec;
    size_t nrec;
    size_t currsize;
} records_t;

char *create_number(records_t *R, size_t numbytes);
int cmp_func(const void *a, const void *b);
void read_records(FILE *filestream, records_t *R);
void print_records(records_t *R);
records_t *create_records(void);

int main(void) {
    records_t *R;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("doublec.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error reading file");
        return 1;
    }

    R = create_records();

    read_records(fp, R);

    printf("\nOriginal Records:\n");
    print_records(R);

    qsort(R->rec, R->nrec, sizeof(record_t), cmp_func);

    printf("\nSorted Records:\n");
    print_records(R);

    free(R->rec);
    R->rec = NULL;

    free(R);
    R = NULL;

    return 0;
}

void read_records(FILE *filestream, records_t *R) {
    char *number;
    size_t w_size, d_size, numbytes;

    while (fscanf(filestream, "%999s %999s", R->rec[R->nrec].whole, R->rec[R->nrec].decimal) == 2) {
        w_size = strlen(R->rec[R->nrec].whole);
        d_size = strlen(R->rec[R->nrec].decimal);

        numbytes = w_size + d_size + 2;

        number = create_number(R, numbytes);

        R->rec[R->nrec].number = atof(number);

        if (R->currsize == R->nrec) {
            R->currsize *= 2;
            R->rec = realloc(R->rec, R->currsize * sizeof(record_t));
            if (R->rec == NULL) {
                printf("Cannot reallocate %zu members.\n", R->currsize);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        free(number);
        number = NULL;

        R->nrec++;
    }
}

char *create_number(records_t *R, size_t numbytes) {
    char *result;
    const char *decimal = ".";

    result = malloc(numbytes);
    if (result == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot allocate %zu bytes for number.\n", numbytes);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    *result = '\0';

    strcat(result, R->rec[R->nrec].whole);
    strcat(result, decimal);
    strcat(result, R->rec[R->nrec].decimal);

    return result;
}

void print_records(records_t *R) {
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < R->nrec; i++) {
        printf("Whole Number: %-5s Decimal: %-8s Number: %-7f\n", R->rec[i].whole, 
                                                                  R->rec[i].decimal, 
                                                                  R->rec[i].number);
    }
}

int cmp_func(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const record_t *num1 = (const record_t *)a;
    const record_t *num2 = (const record_t *)b;

    if (num1->number > num2->number) {
        return +1;
    } else if (num1->number < num2->number) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

records_t *create_records(void) {
    records_t *R = malloc(sizeof(*R));
    if (R == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot allocate struct.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    R->nrec = 0;

    R->currsize = INITIALSIZE;

    R->rec = malloc(R->currsize * sizeof(record_t));
    if (R->rec == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot allocate initial %zu members.\n", R->currsize);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return R;
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for helping me with this. You've really cleared things up. Kudos.

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt has some issues:

- The `number` field in the `record` structure seems to serve no useful purpose.
- reading the file in binary mode seems wasteful since it could be parsed easily as test strings this way:

  ```
  fscanf(input, "%999s %999s", z->whole, z->decimal);
  ```

You could even make the source file completely readable by separating the whole and decimal parts with a `.` and would then use `"%999s.%999s"` as a format string.

You can compare the numbers in string format by taking the following steps:

- skip any initial zeroes in both *whole* parts
- compare the resulting strings lengths: if they differ, return -1 if the first is shorter and 1 if it is longer.
- if both strings have the same length, compare them. If they differ, the result of the comparison should be returned, ie return the result of `strcmp(a->whole, b->whole)`.
- if both *whole* parts are equal, normalize the factional parts by removing the trailing zeroes.
- the comparison result is the result of comparing these strings, ie: `return strcmp(a->decimal, b->decimal);`

Writing the code is your task now. Ideally, your code should implement the above steps without changing the records.

Comment: You may need to explain what you mean by "the result of the comparison" (ie, `strcmp`).